# How to tap on Image view from a cell which is in a table view

Tags: ios, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation, xcode-instruments

I have a image view(tapping on which i get a popover) inside a cell associated in table views.
Log element tree captures the static text 'Picture' but it doesn't show associated image view with it.

My flow is like tables -> cells( have around 4 cells which are static texts)

These cells in turn have textfields attached with them.
     cell1-> textfields1
     cell2-> textfields2
     cell3-> textfields3
     cell4-> has just an image.

How do I access this Image?

```
  var imageId = table[0].cells()[4];

  imageId.images();
```

Dis not return anything.

Comment: I think you have to do this by making custom cell

Comment: How do I make a custom cell? and access it?

Comment: @MH babu I dont want to make any code change on my master.. I just want to access the image view directly. without changing it to a button. Will that be possible ?

Comment: why don't you tap that cell ?? with table[0].cells()[4].tap() .. no matter what is there . the tap should happen

Comment: or check it with logElementTree();

Answer (score 0):

i think u can configure ur cell like this:

(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]autorelease];
```

}

```
    CGRect Frame4 = CGRectMake(10.0, 30.0, 50.0, 40.0);
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    button.frame = Frame4;
    [button setTitle:@"Click" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    [button addTarget:self
           action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:button];




return cell;
```

}

and then add button action event :

- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender{

  // in sender u can get which button is pressed 
  //do something
  }

please replace " UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure " for ur desire image Button